# Is it possible to trigger a method on selection of Lightning:listView checkbox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, list-view

I have a listview that is populated with a custom object "Milestone__c" and I was wondering if it's possible to fire a JS event on selection of one of the checkboxes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a List View Button that opens a VF page. Then , you can invoke Lightning components from the VF Page using Lightning out.